# How can I stop my camera clipping through terrain?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Having a bit of a problem in Unity3D. I have a fly camera with both a box collider and rigidbody, and it still moves through my terrain, which has a terrain collider and a rigidbody. The thing is, it interacts with my capsules just fine, bounces them away and everything. Obvious this is the exact opposite of what I want ha ha...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FlyCamera : MonoBehaviour
{.   
    /*
Writen by Windexglow 11-13-10.  Use it, edit it, steal it I don't care.  
Converted to C# 27-02-13 - no credit wanted.
Simple flycam I made, since I couldn't find any others made public.  
Made simple to use (drag and drop, done) for regular keyboard layout  
wasd : basic movement
shift : Makes camera accelerate
space : Moves camera on X and Z axis only.  So camera doesn't gain any height*/




float mainSpeed = 25.0f; //regular speed
float shiftAdd = 250.0f; //multiplied by how long shift is held.  Basically running
float maxShift = 1000.0f; //Maximum speed when holdin gshift
float camSens = 0.25f; //How sensitive it with mouse
private Vector3 lastMouse = new Vector3(255, 255, 255); //kind of in the middle of the screen, rather than at the top (play)
private float totalRun = 1.0f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(26f, 4f, 14f);
    }

    lastMouse = Input.mousePosition - lastMouse;
    lastMouse = new Vector3(-lastMouse.y * camSens, lastMouse.x * camSens, 0);
    lastMouse = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x + lastMouse.x, transform.eulerAngles.y + lastMouse.y, 0);
    transform.eulerAngles = lastMouse;
    lastMouse = Input.mousePosition;
    //Mouse  camera angle done.  

    //Keyboard commands
    float f = 0.0f;
    Vector3 p = GetBaseInput();
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        totalRun += Time.deltaTime;
        p = p * totalRun * shiftAdd;
        p.x = Mathf.Clamp(p.x, -maxShift, maxShift);
        p.y = Mathf.Clamp(p.y, -maxShift, maxShift);
        p.z = Mathf.Clamp(p.z, -maxShift, maxShift);
    }
    else
    {
        totalRun = Mathf.Clamp(totalRun * 0.5f, 1f, 1000f);
        p = p * mainSpeed;
    }

    p = p * Time.deltaTime;
    Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    { //If player wants to move on X and Z axis only
        transform.Translate(p);
        newPosition.x = transform.position.x;
        newPosition.z = transform.position.z;
        transform.position = newPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        transform.Translate(p);
    }

}

private Vector3 GetBaseInput()
{ //returns the basic values, if it's 0 than it's not active.
    Vector3 p_Velocity = new Vector3();
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        if (transform.position.x > 2 && transform.position.x < 53)
        {
            if (transform.position.y > 0 && transform.position.y < 40)
            {
                if (transform.position.z > 5 && transform.position.z < 52)
                {
                    p_Velocity += new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
                }

            }

        }

    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        if (transform.position.x > 2 && transform.position.x < 53)
        {
            if (transform.position.y > 0 && transform.position.y < 40)
            {
                if (transform.position.z > 5 && transform.position.z < 52)
                {
                    p_Velocity += new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
                }

            }

        }

    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        if (transform.position.x > 2 && transform.position.x < 53)
        {
            if (transform.position.y > 0 && transform.position.y < 40)
            {
                if (transform.position.z > 5 && transform.position.z < 52)
                {
                    p_Velocity += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
                }

            }

        }

    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        if (transform.position.x > 2 && transform.position.x < 53)
        {
            if (transform.position.y > 0 && transform.position.y < 40)
            {
                if (transform.position.z > 5 && transform.position.z < 52)
                {
                    p_Velocity += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
                }

            }

        }

    }
    return p_Velocity;



}
```

}

This flycam isn't mine so if it's not optimal for the use I'm looking for, please notify me about that too.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are. Transforming it not adding velocity thats why it is crossing the collider 
You need to get reference of the rigidbody then add velocity to it
Then it won't cross the collider

You need to modify your code for that
Where you are transforming
Instead of transforming
You need to 
Rigidbody.velocity= vector3(.....)

Answer (score -2):

Never mind, I fixed the problem.
I ended up having Kinematic ticked on the box collider of the camera, so that must have messed it up.

Comment: That is not your problem. You will likely still see your issue. It's because you are updating the position using the transform (and not the rigidbody) on the Update cycle. You should be updating the position on the Fixed cycle using rigidbody. Otherwise Unity won't check for collisions during every frame of movement.